# В каких случаях надо ставить двоеточие?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужно ли ставить двоеточие после слов: доход, штраф, прибыль, убытки?
Например, Доход: 5000; Штраф: 7000; Прибыль: 19000; Убытки: 3000.
И еще одно. Нужно ли двоеточие в следующих случаях?
1) Удалить видео: 4000;
2) Удалить публикацию: 17000;
3) Замять скандал: 13000.
После двоеточия указана сумма, которую надо оплатить.

Comment: Лучше при таком обилии цифр использовать табличные формы широко распространённых программ.

Comment: У Розенталя есть нечто похожее про тире, я думаю, оно будет более уместно в сплошном тексте:
"2. Тире ставится в неполных предложениях при параллелизме конструкций (предложений или частей предложения): Тёркин — дальше. Автор — вслед (Тв.); Забора — нет. Ворот — нет. Границ — нет."
http://old-rozental.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=362

Answer (score 1):

[Розенталь пишет](http://old-rozental.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=362), что тире ставится в неполном предложении, составляющем часть сложного предложения, когда пропущенный член (обычно сказуемое) восстанавливается из предыдущей части фразы и в месте пропуска делается пауза: *У него в глазах — как бы поскорее отделаться от меня*

В нашем случае: "Доход составляет 5000 рублей" => "Доход — 5000 рублей".

Но если ваш документ выглядит как анкета, то правильнее будет поставить двоеточие (после двоеточия — ответ). (http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=260836)